# Runtime error: End of file

Tags: fortran, runtime, fortran90, fortran95

I have a data file with 84480 lines, I split them into 20 different files in a subroutine each having 4224 lines. Now I want to use these files one by one in another subroutine and do some analysis. But when I tried, I'm getting the runtime error: end of file.

Here is the structure of the main program

```
real (kind = 8) :: x(84480),y(84480),x1(4424),y1(4424)
open(1000,file='datafile.txt',status='old') 
n = 20          ! number of configurations
m = 84480       ! total number of lines in all configurations  
p = 4224        ! number of lines in a single configuration
no = 100        ! starting file number configurations
do i=1,m
     read(1000,*) x(i),y(i)
end do  
call split(x,y,m,n)
do i = 1,20
    open(no)
    do j = 1,p
        read(no,*) x1(j),y1(j)    ! error is occurring in here
    end do
    no = no + 1
end do
end
```

Here is the subroutine

```
subroutine split(x,y,m,n)
integer , intent (in) :: m,n
real (kind = 8) , intent(in) :: x(m),y(m)
integer :: i,k,j,p
p = 100
do i=0,n-1
    k = i*4224
    do j = k+1,k+4224
        write(p,*) x(j),y(j)
    end do
    p = p + 1   
end do
end subroutine split
```

This subroutine is producing output files `fort.100` to `fort.119` correctly. But it shows the following error

> unit = 100, file = 'fort.100'
>   Fortran runtime error: End of file

Where am I going wrong?.

Comment: Try to write a blank line to the end of each file. Also, close your "no" files in the read cycle.

Comment: `@MichaelO.` nope , it is not working. Showing the same error again.

Comment: Well, then you have to name each file explicitely, both for reading and writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of interest here is file connection.  The program here uses two forms of connection: *preconnection* and the `open` statement.  We ignore the connection to `datafile.txt` here.

We see preconnection in the subroutine with

```
write(p,*) x(j),y(j)
```

where the unit number `p` hasn't previously been in an `open` statement.  This is where the default filename `fort.100` (etc.) comes about.

After the subroutine has been called those 20 preconnected units have each had data written.  Each of those connections is positioned at the end of the file.  This is the notable part.

When, after the subroutine, we come to the loop with

```
open(no)
```

we are, because we haven't closed the connection, opening a connection with a unit number which is already connected to a file.  This is perfectly acceptable.  But we have to understand what this means.

The statement `open(no)` has no file specifier which means that the unit remains connected to the file it was connected to previously.  As there is no other specifier given, nothing about the connection is changed.  In particular, the connection is not repositioned: we are still at the end of each file.

So, come the read, we are attempting to read from the file when we are positioned at its end.  Result: an end of file error.

Now, how to solve this?

One way, is to reposition the connection.  Although we may want to `open(no, position='rewind')` we can't do that.  There is, however

```
rewind no  ! An unfortunate unit number name; could also be rewind(no).
```

Alternatively, as suggested in the comments on the question, we could close each connection, and reopen in the loop (with an explicit `position='rewind'`) for the reading.